# Где должна располагаться валидация?

Tags: php, yii2, symfony2, валидация, zend-framework

Дано: контроллер, консольная команда и сервис, содержащий бизнесс логику, например:

```
//UserController
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
     $user = $this->mapRequestToUser($request);
     $this->get('user_service')->create($user);
     //...
}

//CreateUserCommand
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
     //...
     $user = new User();
     $user->setUsername($username);
     //...
     $this->getContainer()->get('user_service')->create($user);
     //...
}

//UserService
public function create(User $user)
{
     //business logic goes here 
}
```

Где лучше расположить валидацию?

1. Сервис должен работать только с валидными данными, валидацию расположить в контроллере и команде перед вызовом метода сервиса.
2. Не доверять данным пришедшим от пользователя (имеется в виду пользователь UserService'a), всегда валидировать данные в сервисе. В случае ошибок валидации кидать Exception.

Хотелось бы услышать за и против в обоих случаях. Если есть какие-то общепринятые стандарты, хотелось бы увидеть ссылку на них и реализацию на github'e.

Comment: Данные в сервис могут прийти и от "нелегальной" программы, из которой выпилена вся валидация. Начать следует с сервиса. И только  потом уже может быть и в UI.

Answer (score 0):

Вы упускаете из вида одно из самых существенных преимуществ, которые дает вам ООП: **инкапсуляцию**.

Класс `User` должен накладывать какие-то ограничения на свои данные и неукоснительно следить за их выполнением. Объекты `User` **всегда** должны быть валидными. Ни один из методов класса `User` не должен позволять этой сущности переходить в невалидное состояние.

Например, вот так может выглядеть тривиальная реализация класса `User`

```
class User
{
    private $id;
    private $username;

    public function __construct(UserId $id, $username)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->setUsername($username);
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }


    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]{3, 10}$/i', $username)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid username');
        }

        $this->username = $username;
    }
}
```

Внимательно рассмотрите реализацию класса `User` выше. Она накладывает сразу несколько ограничений на ваших пользователей:

1. Нельзя изменить ID пользователя. Согласитесь, реализация, которая позволяет это сделать выглядит очень-очень странно.
2. ID пользователя имеет строго определенный формат, который определяется в классе `UserId`. Модель не позволит вам использовать в качестве идентификатора что-то, что им не является.
3. Имя пользователя обязано содержать от 3 до 10 символов английского алфавита. Нет способа задать пользователю неверное имя.

Эти ограничения позволяют вам полностью избавится от мыслей о том, где именно проводить валидацию объектов `User`. Если вы передает пользователя в функцию/метод/сервис вы всегда знаете, что этот пользователь валиден.

Comment: 1. setId может понадобиться при клонировании сущности, чтобы сохранить объект ему надо будет обнулить id, иначе он обновит уже имеющийся. 2. С какой целью так усложнять? 3. Допустим у пользователя должно быть обязательно заполнено одно из двух полей, например либо email, либо телефон. Как с этим будет справляться модель?

Comment: 1. Используйте UUID для идентификатора и выдавайте новый при клонировании. Либо используйте статический копирующий конструктор, предавая туда новый ID. 2. Чтобы гарантировать, что ваша модель всегда валидна и вы **внезапно** не оказались в ситуации, что что-то не работает. 3. Два статических конструктора и `private function __constructor`.

Comment: @danil, все эти _сложности_, как вы выразились, называются "защитное программирование". Опыт показывает, что вместе с инкапсуляцией и статической типизацией - это лучший способ избежать непредсказуемого, хрупкого, ломучего и не поддерживаемого говнокода. Не верите мне - посмотрите вот [этот доклад](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3T9-FilHVI). Возможно, Марко будет убедительнее меня :)

Comment: @AmsTaFFix, вы путаете невалидность конкретной сущности и модели предметной области в целом. Ну и _инваринаты_ могут поддреживаться не только на уровне отдельных сущностей, но и на уровне агрегатов и/или системы в целом (через сервисы).

Comment: Собственно сам вопрос именно о валидации отдельных сущностей, а не вообще всего-всего, так что мне кажется я вполне на него ответил :)

Comment: @dmitriy-simushev согласен, путаю :)

Answer (score 0):

Если мы говорим о самом простом случае использования Symfony2/3 и Doctrine, то:

1. Внутри сущности валидируйте все входящие данные, которые возможно, т.е. формат email'а, числа (если они должны быть больше нуля, или неотрицательными и прочее), приведение типов и прочее-прочее
2. Как только появляются какие-то сложные проверки (связанные с внутренним состоянием сущности или какими-то внешними факторами) используйте [validator](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/validation.html) для осуществления этих проверок

Насчет места валидации сущности. Тут зависит от того, что вы пишите.

- Если это какой-то бизнес-проект и он непереиспользуем никаким образом, то можно делать проверки в клиентском коде и отправлять в сервисы
- Если же проект будет переиспользован (опенсорс или внутри компании), то безопаснее проводить проверку на валидность внутри сервиса

Comment: Сама идея перехода модели в невалидное состояние - противоречит основным концепциям DDD. Фактически, основное назначение модели - инкапсуляция бизнес логики и поддержание инвариантов. Выставляя "кишки" модели напоказ через сеттеры и вынося валидацию во вне (пусть будет Validator, хотя есть и другие варианты) вы превращаете **модель** в **DTO**.

Comment: во-первых невалидность сущности может быть не только в её данных (невалидный email, формат идентификатора и прочее), но так же и "состоянии" самой модели, к примеру "в зависимости от значения этого поля, должны быть заполнено это и это поле", во вторых валидность сущности может определяться не только её внутренним состоянием, но так же она может определяться и какими-то внешними факторами. В третьих тут никто не говорил про DDD и её модели, тут просто сущности, которые по большому счету представляют собой маппинг на таблицы в БД, все

Comment: Внешние проверки должны быть **полностью** внешними. Используя хаки вроде уникального ID модели через Validator,  вы, тем самым, помещаете лишнюю ответственность  в сущность. Правильным местом проверок _внешних инвариантов_ является либо сущность более высокого уровня (читай агрегат) либо сервис. Таким проверкам не место в сущности.

Comment: Внешние проверки и есть полностью внешние, которые можно осуществить при помощи validator'а(их настройку можно проводить как в PHP, так и в Yaml и аннотации). Про использование хаков для проверки уникальности идентификатора я ничего не говорил. Так проверка на валидность и делается внешне, оставляя саму сущность простой.

Comment: Эм... Вы меня видимо не поняли. Префразирую: _внешние проверки должны располагаться отдельно от сущности, внутренние должны выполнятся постоянно, не позволяя сущности прийти в невалидное состояние_. Ну а использование Validator - прямая дорога к лапшекоду и перемешиванию отвественности

Comment: Согласен про внутренние проверки, их нужно проводить всегда и кидать исключения, если что-то не так. Почему же использование Validator'а приведет к лапшекоду? Вы хотите сказать, что YAML файл в котором описаны все проверки сущности приведет к лапшекоду? Как? Или же сущность, в которой нет ни слова про валидацию валидатором как-то приведет к лапшекоду? Или запись, типа $this->validator->validate($entity); приведет к лапшекоду? Я чего-то явно не понимаю.

Comment: Если те проверки, что вы называете "внешними" относятся к предметной области, то они должны быть в **явном** реализованы в коде, не допуская перехода модели предметной области в целом в невалидное состояние. Если внешние проверки относятся к инфраструктуре (например уникальность идентификаторов сущностей), то им нечего делать в модели предметной области: они должны быть в явном виде реализованы в инфраструктурных элементах (контролерах, сервисах, реализациях репозиториев и проч. в зависимости от проверки). С учетом этого, Validator - не нужен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51878/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-amstaffix).